# Is it legal to vape on an international flight?

Tags: drugs, smoking

I'll be travelling to the States from Ireland this summer using KLM. I was wondering whether it's legal to vape aboard the plane. I suffer from anxiety and find vaping really helps me.

AFAIK, vaping laws in most countries aren't covered by tobacco regulation which ban smoking in buildings or on airplanes but I could be wrong.

Comment: Regardless of laws, if you were sitting next to me and started vaping (and producing huge clouds of vapor) I would be complaining to the flight attendants ASAP

Comment: Confirmed by LGW Gatwick Airport [guide](https://www.gatwick-airport-guide.co.uk/e-cigarettes.html): *Using e-cigarettes on the plane is not permitted by any airline.*

Comment: Are you sure about "vaping laws in most countries aren't covered by tobacco regulation"? To me, it seems the contrary. In any case: do not start using sleeping pills on flight: try them few week before, at home. I saw a medical emergency near my seat. Strong "nausea" is seldom, but it happens. You do not want to be blocked on a stinky and very tiny WC for hours.

Answer (score 22):

From the KLM website: "Using an electronic cigarette or recharging it or its batteries is never allowed on board."
https://www.klm.co.uk/information/baggage/restricted-items-hand-baggage

Comment: Beat me by 5 seconds

Comment: Apologies, it's not often I Google-fu faster than anyone!!

Comment: I had googled it, I was just nicely formatting my answer from exactly the same source .. lol

Answer (score 16):

Since the flight is to the US, the US Federal law applies. The US Federal law forbids vaping (use of e-cigarettes) on commercial flights. See [the US DOT announcement on their regulation update on the matter](https://www.transportation.gov/airconsumer/E-Cigarette_Final_Rule):

> The Department interprets the existing Part 252 to prohibit e-cigarette use, but is codifying this interpretation.

Answer (score 13):

Every airline I have ever flow on explicitly prohibits vaping on flights.

Comment: I'd note that 7-8 years ago when vaping was still new, [regulations were a lot less clear](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/39375/can-you-use-vapes-e-cigs-in-seattle-airport-or-on-a-flight?noredirect=1&lq=1). But by now they're banned everywhere.

Comment: Every commercial airline you've never flown on also prohibits it!

Answer (score 9):

I will give a much broader negative answer. It contains a [heating element](https://www.faa.gov/hazmat/packsafe/more_info/?hazmat=13)

> Heat producing articles, Battery or Electrically Powered

> These are allowed in checked and carry-on baggage, with airline approval, when a component (battery, fuse, heat element) is isolated to prevent unintentional activation and generation of heat during transport.

Answer (score 2):

Smoking is not legal in planes even electronic ones (even in the bathroom), They'll tell you this at the airport. Checkout this document from the US DOT
[here](https://www.transportation.gov/sites/dot.gov/files/docs/E-Cigarette_Final_Rule_0.pdf)

Comment: I already posted a link to this rule in my answer.

Comment: @littleadv perhaps the identity of the rule linked in your answer would have been more obvious had the hyperlink text been more descriptive than "here" (not that this answer is doing any better in that regard).